# How can I get my python code to look through the string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am making a discord python bot for DnD. I have gotten the bot to recognize a `!roll` command and I have gotten it to recognize equations if they are all spaced out. For example, `!roll d6 + d6 × d20`.

What I am struggling with is getting the bot to take a command that is all in one "word", for example, `!roll d6+d6×d20`. I am trying to make a code that will separate this "word" at the operations. The result should look like the first example.

I have some code that I will add below for what I have already. I am working on one operation at a time so I just need help working out the one and then I can just use it for all the others.

Also, I just have it printing "e" for an indication right now. Please change it if you need to. I appreciate any help I can get.

```
prompt = "!roll 2d8 + d20 /d4+ d6"
a = "+"
b = "×"
c = "÷"
d = "/"
e = "<"
f = ">"
g = "%"
h = "*"
sp = " "

for x in prompt:
    e = prompt.index(x)
    if (x == a) and (prompt[e -1] == " ") and (prompt[e+1] == " "):
        continue
    else:
        print("e")

print(prompt)
```

Comment: Google "writing parser in python". There are libraries that can assist with this.

Comment: `' '.join(re.split('([+|-|×])', '!roll d6+d6×d20'))`?

Comment: @It_is_Chris would I need to import re? And what is the ' ' at the beginning?

Comment: @Barmar, thank you this helps me look into things

Comment: @ginger__tree Yes, you would need to `import re` and that is the separator to join the items in the list back together with a space: `' '.join(['hello', 'world'])` Then just add whatever you want to separate the original string on here (your math operations): `([+|-|×])`

Comment: @It_is_Chris and there is my answer! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try this, here's a way you can do it without regular expressions:

```py
from random import randint

def roll(dice_string):
    result = ""
    for index in range(len(dice_string)):
        char = dice_string[index]
        if char.isdigit() and (index == len(dice_string) - 1 or not dice_string[index + 1].isdigit()):
            result += char + ")"
        else:
            result += char
    result = result.replace('d', '~~~')
    result = result.replace('~~~', 'randint(1, ')
    result = result.replace('x', '*')
    result = result[6:]
    print(result)
    try:
        result = eval(result)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Whoops:", e)
    return int(result)

print(roll("!roll d6+d6xd20"))
```

Admittedly it's a little bit hacky, but it seems to be working.

Comment: Thank you, however, I already have a roll function and such. So the re works fine for me.

Comment: @ginger__tree Sweet, have fun